# How to remove the in-page scrollbar in this template

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I was working with this template https://demos.freehtml5.co/roxy/.
I am unable to remove the in-page scrollbar visible at the right side of every pages.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example here, and please [do not simply paste a link of your page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

```
style="overflow: hidden;"
```

On the body tag should work

Answer (score 0):

apply this

```
body{
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this removes browser scrollbar. I need to remove in-page scrollbar.

Comment: I tried it using developer tools, it removed the in-page scrollbar only.

Comment: no problem @Prakash , if this answer helps you in anyway, you can accept it, it would help me grow my profile. Thank You

Comment: Hi, just to let you know, by putting this code the website worked fine on a desktop browser but the pages got locked on a mobile screen, i.e. became un-scrollable.

Comment: @Prakash nope it is working well on mine ...can you send me the link of the site after updating this

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Though I have changed the template and is developing on a different one.

Comment: @Prakash no problem

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you please guide me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68522711/ by saying what else do I need to add to the the actual .js file.