# Display/Hide input fields based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am a novice in JS and learning. Please help me in correcting the code.

The inputs are:

1. radio-button-1; radio-button-2;
2. input-fields-set-1; input-fields-set-2; input-field-submit.

What I want to achieve is:

On page load only radio-button-1 and radio-button-2 will be displayed. On clicking radio-button-1 input-fields-set-1 and input-field-submit will be displayed but on clicking radio-button-2 input-fields-set-2 and input-field-submit will be displayed.

The complete codes are given below. On running these on http://jsfiddle.net/ its working perfectly but on a website on clicking any of the radio buttons nothing is appearing. I have uploaded the codes on https://testing2601.000webhostapp.com/ for testing purpose and there its not working.

Also please note that all of the input fields in set-1 and set-2 are mandatory fields.

Complete codes from the .js and .html files -

```js
function ageCheck() {
    if  (document.getElementById('below').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifBelow').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifAbove').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifChecked').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('above').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifBelow').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifAbove').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifChecked').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else    {
        document.getElementById('ifAbove').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifBelow').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifChecked').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body >
<div>
  <form method="post" name="childDetails" action="example.php">
    <div class="radioB">
      <div class="a">
        <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:ageCheck();" id="below" name="age" >
        <label for="below">Age of my child is below 4 years.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="a">
        <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:ageCheck();" id="above" name="age" >
        <label for="above">Age of my child is above 4 years.</label>
      </div>                                    
    </div> 
    <div id="ifBelow" class="set-1" style="display: none">
      <div>
        <input type="number" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="DOB of Child in mmddyy" required />
      </div>                                        
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name of the child" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ifAbove" class="set-2" style="display: none">
      <div>
        <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age of your child" required />
      </div>    
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Name of the child" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="hobby" name="hobby" placeholder="Hobby of your child" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="email" id="email-2" name="email-2" placeholder="Your email" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ifChecked" class="set-3" style="display: none">
      <div class="set-3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="proud" name="proud" required>
        <label for="proud">I am a proud parent.</label>
      </div>                                    
      <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="primary" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>       

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On your host, you didn't include jQuery. which cause it to fail. But on the related note, take you your function out of `(ffunction($) { ... }) (jQuery)` block, so that it is available on global scope which is required by your html

Comment: @ AdityaParab, I have done it but it didn't work. Would you please guide me with the complete js code!

Comment: It is perfectly working in [your project](https://testing2601.000webhostapp.com/)

Comment: Yes, I could finally do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your code at https://testing2601.000webhostapp.com/ , I see your javascript code (from main.js) as below so if that's the case that means `ageCheck` is not attached to global so it's not be defined for your HTML to use and that's your root cause on why it's not working.

```
(function($) {    
    
    function ageCheck() {
    if  (document.getElementById('below').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifBelow').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifAbove').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifChecked').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('above').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifBelow').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifAbove').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifChecked').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else    {
        document.getElementById('ifAbove').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifBelow').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifChecked').style.display = 'none';
    }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Would you please correct the code(s) and share here! I'll really appreciate that.